# Unable to make a token transfer

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to simply transfer tokens from one address to another on ropsten but I keep getting this error

> Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

this is the code:

```
const cacheAddress_ = "0xDD963fCdD32ccC802470CdB85A634dE8A47E9257" 
const circulationAddress_ = "0x2dA320D8efF599f11Fe575124020743c9c2E8088"     
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/API_KEY"))

async function transfer() {
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(lvn.ABI, lvn.address)
    const block = await contract.methods.transfer(circulationAddress_, new BigNumber(10**9*10**18)).send({ from: cacheAddress_ })
    const circulationBalance = await contract.methods.balanceOf(circulationAddress_).call()
    const cacheBalance = await getCacheBalance()
    console.log({ circulationBalance, cacheBalance })
}

transfer()
```

I know it's not a problem with infura, Infura definitely exposes the necessary API's for making transactions. I've tried on a local node with rinkeby and i get the same problem. This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48639/the-method-eth-sendtransaction-does-not-exist-is-not-available) because the same error occurs with web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount still comes up as unavailable (same error as above).

One solve might be to sign the token transfer if anybody knows how to do that (i know how to sign a regular eth transaction but not a token transfer)

Comment: What version of web3 are you using?

Comment: Unless something has recently changed, Infura does _not_ support `eth_sendTransaction`. It doesn't know your private key, so it can't support any method that requires a private key.